# htaccess mod_rewrite: Redirect all subdomains, exclude some

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are many similar questions, but I couldn't find an answer to this specific one:

In my .htaccess I have a rewrite to redirect all subdomains to http://example.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I want it to ignore dev.example.com (and maybe some other subdomains). I guess that's easy, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same way as you excluded the main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how would u do this in reverse, if the sub domain doesn't exist forward to the main. but if it does stay on the sub domain.